# With apollo client, how to trigger resubscription using reactive variables?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, subscription

Apollo client and graphql versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.20",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    ...
  }
```

I want to subscribe to a list filtered by user input, in react.

Use reactive variable to store the user input:

```
import { makeVar } from '@apollo/client'

export const searchVar = makeVar('')

function keyDown(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    searchVar(event.target.value)
  }
}

export default function Search() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full text-black cursor-pointer text-sm flex">
      <input
        type="search"
        name="search"
        onKeyDown={keyDown}
        placeholder="Find"
        className="flex-grow px-4 rounded-lg text-sm focus:outline-none"
      />  
    </div>
  )
}
```

Subscription with the reactive variable:

```
import { gql, useSubscription } from '@apollo/client'
import { searchVar } from './search'

const SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
  subscription Customers($searchStr: String!) {
    customer(
      limit: 10
      where: { name: {_ilike: $searchStr} }
    ) {
      name
      addr
    }
  }
`

export default function customers() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useSubscription(
    SUBSCRIPTION,
    {   
      variables: {
        searchStr: searchVar()
      },  
      shouldResubscribe: true,
    }   
  )
  ...
}
```

The subscription is expected to be resubscribed when users input something and press enter, but it doesn't work.
I guess I'm using reactive variables or subscription in a wrong way.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/

```
Most importantly, modifying a reactive variable triggers an update of every active query that depends on that variable, as well an update of the react state associated with any variable values returned from the useReactiveVar React hook.
```

Using useReactiveVar, resubscription is successfully triggerred when the reactive variable is updated.

Comment: Does this also unsubscribe the previous subscription?